# MSXML2 SQL Web Service Call not passing parameters

Tags: sql, xml, web-services

I have a web service that we are using to preform xslt transformation on XML. I am trying to call this web service from SQL(Don't ask, it has to be this way lol). I found this SQL SP on the web and been trying to use it to meet my needs:
http://www.vishalseth.com/post/2009/12/22/Call-a-webservice-from-TSQL-(Stored-Procedure)-using-MSXML.aspx

Here is the description of the web service from the asmx page:

```
POST /JobInvokerService.asmx HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: length
SOAPAction: "http://sqljobabca.org/TransformXML"

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"      xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<soap:Body>
<TransformXML xmlns="http://sqljobabca.org/">
  <inputDataXML>string</inputDataXML>
  <inputTransformXML>string</inputTransformXML>
</TransformXML>
</soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

And here is the SQL I am using to call the SP:
    DECLARE @return_value int,
        @responseText varchar(8000)

```
EXEC    @return_value = [dbo].[spHTTPRequest-Unedited]
    @URI = N'http://localhost:3915/JobInvokerService.asmx',
    @methodName = N'POST',
    @requestBody = N'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        <soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
              <soap:Body>
                <TransformXML xmlns="http://sqljobabca.org">
                  <inputDataXML><NewProductListingRequest xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"><PublicComments/><PrivateComments/><BaseProduct></NewProductListingRequest></inputDataXML>
                  <inputTransformXML><xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0"><xsl:template match="/NewProductListingRequest"></xsl:template></xsl:stylesheet></inputTransformXML>
                </TransformXML>
              </soap:Body>
            </soap:Envelope>',
    @SoapAction = N'"http://sqljobabca.org/TransformXML"',
    @UserName = NULL,
    @Password = NULL,
    @responseText = @responseText OUTPUT

SELECT  @responseText as N'@responseText'
```

I trim out the XML parameters to save space.

After some messing around I can get it to actually hit the web service but the parameters(inputDataXML and inputTransformXML) are null.

Any suggestions?